# JPA and java 8 date API - choosing correct implementation (Instant, LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime)

Tags: jpa, time, java-8, java-time, hibernate-5.x

Which of the available java 8 time API classes is most suitable for JPA entity mapping in following case:

- *contract created at* type of information
- the dates are stored in UTC in the database
- business logic does all calculations in UTC
- dates are displayed in the UI in Europe/Vienna timezone

Most examples I've seen use **LocalDateTime**, but that one doesn't have any notion of time zones. Since all of our business logic should do calculations in UTC and also retrieve/store data in UTC wouldn't **Instant** or **ZonedDateTime** be more appropriate?

What practical implications should one consider, when making a decision about which type to use for JPA entity mappings (eg. inability to add a week to Instant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Instant` is by by definition UTC, so if you are always dealing with UTC, it is sufficient if it has all of the operations you need. `LocalDateTime` is a timestamp without a specific time zone or zone offset, but if you know you are only dealing with UTC, it can be useful for the operations it provides that `Instant` does not.

The most exact type that can carry a definite zone offset, allowing you to preserve the moment of time while converting back and forth between UTC and other time zones is `OffsetDateTime`.  There is a convenient `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant that you can use to fix the offset at +0 hours for UTC. `ZonedDateTime` adds the concept of a `TimeZone` which adds support for things like daylight savings time, a concept which you generally don't need when dealing with UTC unless you want to display the local time in a specific locale.

Comment: Makes sense. For my final decision I found the JSR-000221 JDBC API Specification 4.2 usefull, especially the table in appendix B-4. Will stick to LocalDateTime.

https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html

Comment: can you explain which datatype should be used in `mysql` and `java` entity class, if one opts to use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`?